# Unable to understand why the try and catch is not working as expected in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, try-catch, sails.js

I am new to [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html).I am using [Sails js](http://sailsjs.org/), [Mongo DB](https://www.mongodb.org/?_ga=1.213633104.596951049.1438390068) and [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) in my project. My basic requirement was to find details of all the users from my `user` *collection*. My code is as follows:

```
try{
    user.find().exec(function(err,userData){
    if(err){
         //Capture the error in JSON format
    }else{
         // Return users in JSON format
     }
    });
   }
catch(err){
      // Error Handling
 }
```

Here `user` is a *model* which contains all the `user` details. I had sails lifted my app and then I closed my `MongoDB` connection. I ran the `API` on `DHC` and found the following:

1. When I ran the `API` for the *first* time on `DHC`, the `API` took more than 30 sec to show me an *error* that the `MongoDB` *connection* is not avaliable.
2. When I ran the `API` for the *second* time, The `API` timed out without giving an response.

My Question here why is the *`try`* and *`catch`* block unable to handle such an *error* *exception* effectively in `mongoose` or is it something that I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**
My Requirement is that mongoose should display the error immediately if the DB connection is not present.

Comment: A couple of things to consider; 1) there's no `throw` in your example snippet...the `catch` will only be triggered if something is thrown, and 2) all of the interesting stuff happens inside of your `function(err, userData)`, which is _defined_ inside of the try/catch block but which is probably not _executed_ there...if the execution occurs elsewhere, then of course any exception that gets thrown will not trigger your `catch` block.

Comment: Sorry I missed my error in the code snippet. Can you please elaborate about the second point mentioned in your comment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Try and catch Block is taking more time in Mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741033/try-and-catch-block-is-taking-more-time-in-mongoose)

Comment: @shubhamagiwal It was already expanded upon in the previous question you asked about the same thing. With a "callback", any error is typically  sent as the first argument and no exceptions are typically thrown. Since the method is async then there would generally be no way of knowing if there was an error until the callback is passed that information. Thus, only if you purposely "throw" that error data as an exception then there is no exception to "catch". Typically in such an async call you just "inspect" the error rather than wrap in a try/catch. Nothing thrown, nothing to catch.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I Trying to understand the internal mechanism as to how mongoose works for failed db connection. Find is an Async function so why is it so erractic in capturing the results for multiple times when the api is called for failed db connection. It should atleast be able to capture the error for failed db connection consistently. But as I mentioned in the question it is not able to do the same. I tried to removing try and catch on the find and did the error handling inside it and still got the same result. Can you please help me as to what is the possible reason?

Comment: @shubhamagiwal And we have tried to explain to you on various occasions now, that you do not need to call a try/catch block here. It is not appropriate to the asyncronous methods that you are using. They don't "throw" exceptions.

Comment: Okk. Understood that try and catch block is not necessary. thanks Blakes Seven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let’s take a look at a function that uses a synchronous usage pattern.

```
// Synchronous usage example

var result = syncFn({ num: 1 });

// do the next thing
```

When the function `syncFn` is executed the function executes in sequence until the function
returns and you’re free to do the next thing. In reality, synchronous functions should be
wrapped in a try/catch. For example the code above should be written like this:

```
// Synchronous usage example

var result;

try {
  result = syncFn({ num: 1 });
  // it worked
  // do the next thing
} catch (e) {
  // it failed
}
```

Now let’s take a look at an asynchronous function usage pattern.

```
// Asynchronous usage example

asyncFn({ num: 1 }, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    // it failed
    return;
  }

  // it worked
  // do the next thing
});
```

When we execute `asyncFn` we pass it two arguments. The first argument is the criteria to be used by the function. The second argument is a callback that will execute whenever `asyncFn` calls the callback. `asyncFn` will insert two arguments in the callback – `err` and `result`). We
can use the two arguments to handle errors and do stuff with the result.

The distinction here is that with the asynchronous pattern we do the next thing within the callback of the asynchronous function. And really that’s it.